# is it possible show icon in desktop notification body javascript

Tags: javascript, notifications

Currently i have requirement to show image inside the desktop notification body but I am not sure is it possible or not -

```
notification = new Notification("title", "user1"), {
  icon: baseUrl + '/image/icon.png',
  body: "message"   // here i want add my custom image
});
```

if possible then i need the way to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not add image in *Notification.body* because ***body*** property only accepts string type according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification)

Answer (score 4):

you can use base64 in the icon property

```
new Notification('name',{icon:/*base64 url*/})
```

[here](http://b64.io/) is a site the convert images to base64

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error, if you write it like this you can place pretty much every picture/icon in the notification.

```
var notification = new Notification("Hi there!", {
        icon: 'http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/96/139.jpg',
        body: 'Picture from https://placekitten.com/'
        })
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7s7rwueq/) - code taken from [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/notification)